# How do I uninstall Apple Developer Tools EXCEPT for the iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, developer-tools

I installed the Developer Tools and it ends up I don't really need them and it takes up a lot of room on my small hard drive. However I find the iPhone simulator extremely useful for mobile web development. What exactly do I need to keep on my Mac for the iPhone simulator to continue to run? I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the special nature of the Trash, you should be able to experiment fairly safely. Try moving the whole Developer directory to Trash then moving just /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications back into place. If it doesn't run, try leaving more alone...

This ignores the various hooks installation has into your system, the ones that executing "/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools" script removes. Maybe you should copy the entire /Developer folder somewhere first, then do the official uninstall, then try just restoring that Applications directory.

In fact clone your whole drive first. I'm hoping you are trying to save space because you have moved to a small SSD so you probably have some other storage capable of holding it all?